# What's the difference between --add-exports and --add-opens in Java 9?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

Java 9 (jdk-9+170) does not allow by default an application to see all classes from the JDK, unlike all previous versions of Java, due to the new module system.

To workaround this, the `java` command line offers a new argument `--add-exports` which allows to break encapsulation as follows:

```
java -jar josm.jar \
    --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This is well explained in [JEP 261: Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261).

I have read about a similar option `--add-opens` using the same syntax, <s>but the JEP 261 has not yet been updated to describe it (last update: 2017/03/08 13:58).</s>

**What is the difference between these two options?**

**EDIT**: The [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) has been updated on 2017-09-22 to explain it.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

- With [`--add-exports`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Accessing-Internal-APIs-With--add-exports) the package is exported, meaning all public types and members therein are accessible at compile and run time.
- With [`--add-opens`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Reflectively-Accessing-Internal-APIs-With--add-opens) the package is opened, meaning all types and members (not only public ones!) therein are accessible at run time.

So the main difference at run time is that `--add-opens` allows "deep reflection", meaning access of non-public members. You can typically identify this kind of access by the reflecting code making calls to `setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: This is now explained in JEP 261 as Mark updated the page today: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261

Comment: A command to find which module provides which package:

`java --list-modules | tr @ " " | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n1 java -d`

the name of the module will be shown with the @ while the name of the packages without it

Comment: it is not clear from the answer and @ZhekaKozlov combined if --add-opens enables public types and members to be accessible at **compile time**

Comment: `--add-opens` is only concerned with reflection, which is a run-time concept, and so the flag does not apply to the compiler.