# Issues with Springboot and Apache Ignite deployment on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, ignite

I am currently trying to develop an api that utilizes apache ignite as an in memory cache. In the IDE I am able to get everything running and the ignite cache starts up with no issues. When I try to deploy the war file onto tomcat it seems like there is an issue trying to start up ignite. From what I have seen it looks to be possible but I cant seem to find any configuration settings whether it be in Tomcat or ignite that will allow me to do so.

The following is my pom.xml dependencies

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <ignite.version>2.14.0</ignite.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--To enable tomcat deployment-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

For testing purposes I just start up ignite with

```
Ignition.start()
```

upon requesting an api endpoint to start up the ignite node i see the following error logs in Tomcat

```
`2023-05-18T10:17:23.483-04:00 ERROR 2540 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/test] due to exception [null]

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.<clinit>(IgniteUtils.java:888) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:558) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:541) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:310) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at com.example.demo.testController.test(testController.java:26) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.8]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.address field is unavailable.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1570) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1557) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.bufferAddressOffset(GridUnsafe.java:1557) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.<clinit>(GridUnsafe.java:109) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field long java.nio.Buffer.address accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @34967d5f
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1562) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        ... 66 common frames omitted`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your Tomcat seems to be running under Java 17. All the deployed apps reside in the same `JVM`, so you need to run it with proper startup options (with --add-opens). Please refer to the [docs](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start/java#running-gridgain-with-java-11).

This behaviour was introduced as a part of the Jigsaw project - [JSR 376](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/spec/).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056405/whats-the-difference-between-add-exports-and-add-opens-in-java-9) sheds some light as well.

Comment: I had added these JVM options specified by grid gain within Intellij IDE and created the war file again for deployment on Tomcat, but even with these options set it appears like it does not resolve the issue

Comment: @Andrew you need to run Tomcat itself with these options, it's not being "packaged" into the war in any way.

Comment: What's the problem with shutdown.bat?

Comment: i have set these arguments in the tomcat config file Catalina.bat under the Catalina_Opts and ignite now works, however it doesn't seem like shutdown.bat is working the same as before. Normally when running shutdown.bat it will shutdown the server and close the startup.bat console window. while it does seem to shutdown the server it no longer closes the console. I just want to make sure this is not an issue