# JSON Serialization using Gson for XMLGregorianCalendar with Java 17

Tags: java, json, gson, java-17, xmlgregoriancalendar

I'm using GSON to serialize an Object using JDK 17.0.10.  The object contains XMLGregorianCalendar object which I have registered an adapter for serialization.  The compiling of the application is fine but when the application starts, that's where I have issues and get the following exception when calling GsonBuilder.toJson for an object.

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl#eon' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:368)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:368)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:842)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:812)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:759)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:736)
```

I know Java 11 provided warnings when class objects go into the internals of sun API, related to "Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals by Default" (JEP 396).  In the case of Java 17, those issues become errors and the API expects these to be resolved hence the exception I'm getting in the logs.

I've tried using "--add-exports" parameter on startup for the related package with no success.  Maybe I was doing it wrong?  However, I don't really like doing this and want to fix the problem correctly.

I'm currently using the latest Gson (2.10.1) and have this in my code.

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, new XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer());
```

I personally believe GSON API is calling "new XMLGregorianCalendar()" when I really need it to call "DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar" which would probably solve this issue.  My XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer has code where it does evaluation on the contents of the date but I commented it all out to return a new JsonPrimitive with an empty new String object.  I did this to remove my serialized logic in my class from the picture so I can focus on what is causing the issue on serialization with Java 17.

So, what am I missing? Is there a way to fix this or am I missing something I need to add to my code to solve this issue?  Anybody have any ideas?

Fyi, going to Jackson JSON not a path I want to take.  I would like to fix my Gson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JsonException during converting Java object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173328/jsonexception-during-converting-java-object-to-json)

Comment: See the linked question; you are actually serializing a subclass of `XMLGregorianCalendar`, so you have to use `GsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` instead of `registerTypeAdapter`

Comment: Regarding `--add-exports`, you would probably rather have to use `--add-opens`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44056405 for the difference. However, that would only be a workaround; the proper solution is registering a custom type adapter, as you did.

Comment: I think I overlooked the `--add-opens`.  Still not what I wanted to use.  However, `GsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` did fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: For completeness I have added it as proper answer now, with a bit more information

Comment: Posted accepted answer.  I would've done it myself but I'm not allowed to yet for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` registers the adapter only for the specified class, but not for subclasses. However, `XMLGregorianCalendar` is an abstract class and as seen in the exception you are currently receiving, you are actually serializing the JDK-internal subclass `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl`.

To solve this use [`GsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)) instead of `registerTypeAdapter`.